# How to make "run time" stop appearing in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm just starting to learn Python. When I run a program in Visual Studio I get output that looks like the following:

[image: Run output]

Instead of just showing Hello World or whatever it has:

```
 [Running] python -u "c:\Users\tom\Desktop\HelloWorld\app.py"
```

before everything and:

```
[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.167 seconds at the end
```

It just makes it look a bit messy, I guess maybe because i'm only doing one or two lines at a time as a beginner, but still, wondering if I can stop it, so just shows the output i want printed?

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Debugging > Output Window. You can turn off what you want from there.[image]

Comment: Hi, 

Thank you very much for the reply. But i don't see this option. Along the ribbon at the top there is nothing that says "Tools". It says File, Edit, Selection, View, Go, Debug, Terminal, Help

Thank you

Tom

Comment: @Tom what version of VS are you using? My sample was from VS 2015 Professional. Unless you are using something like vscode then I think they should be similar.